# Amazon price history dataset

Tags: data-request, historical, products, prices

Are there any datasets on Amazon products' price history? http://camelcamelcamel.com/ doesn't make it available and the [Amazon Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) doesn't seem to give access to the price history.

Comment: you could also try to collect your own data with tools such as [import.io](http://import.io/)

Answer (score 5):

[www.keepa.com](http://www.keepa.com) is a similar website to camelcamelcamel. I cannot find a way to download the data but maybe you will.

In addition, [Terapeak](https://www.terapeak.com/services/data-services#pricing) provide a **free** package with limited api calls (500/months) where you can find historical prices.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.isbndb.com has a good API that uses XML calls/responses to get new/used prices from Amazon.com as well as a number of other sites like abebooks, half.com, etc...

Answer (score 4):

You can also scrape (or better yet contact and ask the folks at) https://thetracktor.com which seems to have some great historical data.

**EDIT - Adding example:**

- `https://thetracktor.com/ajax/prices/?id=881549&days=90` is the JSON response powering the graph at `https://thetracktor.com/detail/B0054JJ0QW/`, for example.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @DeerHunter can you elaborate? `https://thetracktor.com/ajax/prices/?id=881549&days=90` is the JSON response powering the graph at `https://thetracktor.com/detail/B0054JJ0QW/`, for example.

Comment: Am getting 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @DeerHunter - weird, it works just fine for me. Screenshot: http://note.io/1j1VsWM

Answer (score 1):

keepa.com is offering an api (https://keepa.com/#!pricedataapi), they even offering an SDK for Java: https://github.com/keepacom/api_backend . But it seems like you have to pay for it..

Answer (score 1):

EZSiteTracker’s Price Tracking Tool allows you to detect the price change of your favorite product/s online and get instant notifications via email. Visit: http://www.ezsitetracker.com/PriceTracking

Answer (score 0):

I believe this api provides exactly what you are looking for - [Amazon Price History API](https://rapidapi.com/Megatvini/api/amazon-price-history)

I recently published it and made available virtually for free in case you only need info about a few products.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: "Page not found" error.