# Is there any public dataset related to fashion objects?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, fashion

I'm looking for large datasets of images related to the fashion industry. It could be garments or people in the street wearing some dress or models. I saw a related [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/155/publicly-available-datasets) but it's very general and does not contain any reference to the industry I'm interested in. Any idea???

Comment: @Spacedman you are completely wrong. My question is not off-topic. One of the most votes questions is [this](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/155/publicly-available-datasets). You can find people asking for datasets [1](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/422/publicly-available-social-network-datasets-apis), [2](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/587/where-can-i-download-historical-market-capitalization-and-daily-turnover-data-fo), [3](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/997/where-can-i-find-free-spatio-temporal-dataset-for-download).

Comment: Just because this site is under-moderated doesn't make it right. See http://meta.datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/burninate-dataset "Requests for data are migrated to OpenData, where they belong". Your Q is a request for data. The mods should migrate it.

Comment: There's also a [meta question](http://meta.datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12/is-asking-about-data-sets-off-topic/68) which is exactly on whether such questions are on-topic or not. The consensus seemed to be that questions asking for links to datasets are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Spacedman hbaderts thank you guys, very helpful comments. It looks it's more important to locate one question in a specific place than to answer it. I suggest you both do the same with all the other questions related to datasets. Do you know any answer to my question, _after we make all the necessary steps to locate the text in the exact place you think it is very important to be_?

Comment: Perhaps http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/amazon-price-history-dataset ? Also, have you considered Wikipedia or Wikidata as data sources?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Fashion-MNIST dataset by Zolando Research here. The images are in a 28x28 pixel format. https://www.kaggle.com/zalando-research/fashionmnist

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DeepFashion dataset:

http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/DeepFashion.html

> - DeepFashion contains over 800,000 diverse fashion images ranging from well-posed shop images to unconstrained consumer photos.
> - DeepFashion is annotated with rich information of clothing items. Each image in this dataset is labeled with 50 categories, 1,000 descriptive attributes, bounding box and clothing landmarks.
> - DeepFashion contains over 300,000 cross-pose/cross-domain image pairs.

[image]

> Four benchmarks are developed using the DeepFashion database, including Attribute Prediction, Consumer-to-shop Clothes Retrieval, In-shop Clothes Retrieval, and Landmark Detection. The data and annotations of these benchmarks can be also employed as the training and test sets for the following computer vision tasks, such as Clothes Detection, Clothes Recognition, and Image Retrieval.

---

License: Non-commercial, research purposes