# Back and front images for clothing

Tags: machine-learning, images, fashion

I am developing an AI application for clothes designing.

To train the model we need front and back images of clothing (T-shirts, formal shirts, pants etc.) drawings/designs.

Like this:

[image]

[image]

I want a dataset of 5000 front and back images of clothes.

Comment: Did you mean clothes *designing*? Must the clothes be laid flat versus worn by a model? Can they be photographs of actual clothing, or only drawings/designs like in the examples?

Comment: 1) Must the clothes be laid ...... 

2)only drawings/designs like in the examples @csk

Comment: related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15624/1511